# Is the kernel $\vert d_X - d_Y \vert^p$ conditionally negative definite?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, tensor, kernels

Given two finite metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, for $p > 0$, define the kernel ($4$-D tensor) $K$ on $(X \times Y)^2$ by:
$$K\big( (x_i, y_k), (x_j, y_l) \big) = \vert d_X(x_i, x_j) - d_Y(y_k, y_l) \vert^p.$$

Is this kernel conditionally negative definite (CND), or is there any value of $p$ for which it is CND?

I tested numerically in Python for various values of $p$, but the result ***seems*** to indicate that for small $p$, we have a CND kernel, but only with "high probability", not always. And also this "probability" seems to decrease linearly, w.r.t $p$. But also note that in this experiment, the value $z^T 1$ is only very close to zero, due to the numerical precision, which ***might*** have impact on the final value of $z^T K z$.

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if use_cuda else "cpu")
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True

dx = 5
dy = 3
nx = 100
ny = 120

X = torch.randn((nx, dx)).to(device)
Y = torch.randn((ny, dy)).to(device)
Cx = torch.cdist(X, X, 2.0) # Euclidean distance matrix
Cy = torch.cdist(Y, Y, 2.0) # Euclidean distance matrix

n = 5000
percentage_positive = []
list_p = np.arange(0.1, 2.5, 0.4)
for p in tqdm(list_p):
    K = torch.abs(Cx[:,None,:,None] - Cy[None,:,None,:])**p
    K = K.reshape(nx * ny, nx * ny)  

    is_pos = []
    for _ in range(n):
        z = torch.randn(nx*ny).to(device)
        z = z - z.mean()
        is_pos.append((z.T @ K @ z).item() > 0)
    percentage_positive.append(sum(is_pos) / n * 100)

plt.plot(list_p, percentage_positive, color="blue")
plt.title("Percentage of positive values")
plt.xlabel("Values of $p$")
plt.ylabel("Percentage (%)")
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Comment: "Negative definite" is often used for "conditionally negative definite". Since this is $\ge 0$ as a function and not identically zero, it clearly can't define a negative definite kernel in the rigourous sense (in the sense that, written as a matrix $M$, $X^tMX\le 0$ for every $X$: just take $X$ constant vector equal to $1$).

Comment: @YCor: thank you for your response. Just to clarify: by "negative definite", I mean the inequality $x^T K x \leq 0$, for every $x$, whereas by "conditionally negative definite", I mean it only holds for every $x$ such that $x^T 1 = 0$. The "negative definite" in this case is clearly impossible, as you pointed out. Do you have any clue for the "conditionally negative definite"?